LINQ subset results grouped from multi-table join
I have 4 tables:
USER:
-userKey
-userName

ROLE:
-roleKey
-roleDesc

PERMISSION:
-permissionKey
-permissionDesc

USERROLEPERMISSION:
-userKey
-roleKey
-permissionKey


Here is the db query...
select
u.userKey,
u.userName,
r.roleKey,
r.roleDesc,
p.permissionKey,
p.permissonDesc
FROM
USER u
JOIN USERROLEPERMISSION urp  on u.userKey = urp.userKey
JOIN ROLE r on urp.roleKey = r.roleKey
JOIN PERMISSION p on urp.permissionKey = p.permissionKey


Here is the db result...
userkey username                rolekey roledesc                permissionkey   permissiondesc
1       Captain Jack Sparrow    1       Admin                   1               Admin
1       Captain Jack Sparrow    2       Generic Data Access     5               Update
1       Captain Jack Sparrow    2       Generic Data Access     3               Read


I want to run a LINQ query to yield...
[
    {
        "userKey": 1,
        "userName": "Captain Jack Sparrow",
        "rolePermissionSet": [
            {
                "roleKey": 1,
                "roleDesc": "Admin",
                "permissionSet": [
                    {
                        "permissionKey": 1,
                        "permissionDesc": "Admin",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "roleKey": 2,
                "roleDesc": "Generic Data Access",
                "permissionSet": [
                    {
                        "permissionKey": 5,
                        "permissionDesc": "Update",
                    },
                    {
                        "permissionKey": 3,
                        "permissionDesc": "Read",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]


I tried something like the following, but it never grouped how I wanted... would have a separate element for every user/role/permission combination. I'm thinking using group/by?? but I can't get the syntax right.  All the samples I looked at are rather elementary...
            var query =
                (from u in _dbContext.Users
                join urp in _dbContext.SAIMUserRolePermissions on u.UserKey equals urp.UserKey
                 select new UserRolePermissionSet
                 {
                     UserKey = u.UserKey,
                     UserName = u.UserName,
                     RolePermissionSet = (from rd in _dbContext.RoleDescriptions
                            where urp.UserKey == u.UserKey
                            where urp.RoleKey == rd.RoleKey
                            select new RolePermissionSet
                            {
                                RoleKey = rd.RoleKey,
                                RoleDescription = rd.RoleDescription,
                                PermissionSet = (from pd in _dbContext.PermissionDescriptions
                                              where urp.UserKey == u.UserKey
                                              where urp.RoleKey == rd.RoleKey
                                              where urp.RolePermissionKey == pd.RolePermissionKey
                                              select new RolePermissionDesc
                                              {
                                                  RolePermissionKey = pd.RolePermissionKey,
                                                  RolePermissionDescription = pd.RolePermissionDescription
                                              }).ToList()
                            }).ToList(),
                 }).ToListAsync();

Here are the models and dbcontext particulars...
    public DbSet<UserRolePermission> SAIMUserRolePermissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleDesc> RoleDescriptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RolePermissionDesc> PermissionDescriptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRolePermissionSet> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRolePermission>().ToTable("userrolepermission");
    modelBuilder.Entity<RoleDesc>().ToTable("role");
    modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermissionDesc>().ToTable("permission");
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("user");

    [Table("userrolepermission")]
    public class UserRolePermission
    {
        [Key()]
        [Column("userrolekey")]
        public long UserRoleKey
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Required()]
        [Column("userkey")]
        public long UserKey
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Required()]
        [Column("rolekey")]
        public long RoleKey
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Required()]
        [Column("rolepermissionkey")]
        public long RolePermissionKey
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
    
    [Table("role")]
    public class RoleDesc
    {
        [Key()]
        [Column("rolekey")]
        public long RoleKey
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Required()]
        [Column("roledesc")]
        public string? RoleDescription
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
    
    [Table("permission")]
    public class RolePermissionDesc
    {
        [Key()]
        [Column("rolepermissionkey")]
        public long RolePermissionKey
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Required()]
        [Column("rolepermissondesc")]
        public string? RolePermissionDescription
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
    
    public class UserRolePermissionSet
    {
        [Key()]
        public long UserKey
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string? UserName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public List<RolePermissionSet>? RolePermissionSet
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    [Table("user")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key()]
        [Column("userkey")]
        public long UserKey
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Column("username")]
        public string? UserName
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }


How to help you if you do not supply classes? LINQ query is build from classes and their navigation properties. Edit your question and add additional details.

sorry about that.  Added the model classes and dbcontext particulars.  Let me know if you need anything else from the code.  Don't want to clutter it up too much.

Well, looks like you do not have appropriare navigation properties and join is needed.

// request only what you need
var query =
    from u in _dbContext.Users
    join urp in _dbContext.SAIMUserRolePermissions on u.UserKey equals urp.UserKey
    join r in _dbContext.RoleDescriptions on urp.roleKey equals r.roleKey
    join p in _dbContext.PermissionDescriptions on urp.permissionKey equals p.permissionKey
    select new
    {
        u.UserKey,
        u.UserName,
        urp.RoleKey,
        r.RoleDescription,
        p.PermissionKey,
        p.PermissionDesc
    };

// materialize the query
var flattentResult = await query.ToListAsync(); 

// perform grouping to achieve desired result on the client side
var result = flattentResult
    .GroupBy(ug => new { ug.UserKey, ug.UserName })
    .Select(g => new UserRolePermissionSet
    {
        userKey = g.Key.UserKey,
        userName = g.Key.UserName,
        rolePermissionSet = g
            .GroupBy(rg => new { rg.RoleKey, rg.RoleDescription })
            .Select(rg => new RolePermissionSet
            {
                RoleKey = rg.Key.RoleKey,
                RoleDescription = rg.Key.RoleDescription,
                PermissionSet = rg.Select(p => new RolePermissionDesc
                {
                    RolePermissionKey = p.PermissionKey,
                    RolePermissionDescription = p.PermissionDesc
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();

